# How to Apply the Coupon Code only to the products that are "Not on Sale" - [Without Special Price]?

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, coupon-codes, special-price

My conditions are working fine when i check out with single product which is not having the special price, The same condition is working fine with the products has special price.

So the problem is with the condition when i have both type of products in my cart i.e. one which is having the Special price and other that doesn't has the Special price, In this condition the coupon is working with both the products. It shouldn't work with the products with the special price.

[image: Screenshot for the condition of Coupon Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Please set action like this screenshot. as i have checked it is working perfect.